# Is it good to begin my response with "Good One"?

Tags: expressions, speech

I am planning to respond a comment in one of the other **forums** in StackExchange! I was wondering if I can begin my response by saying ***"Good one, .."*** to confirm that it was a ***"Good suggestion"***.

In general what are other good choices for similar occasions that are both polite and common in English.

---

**EDIT**
Since I did mention, it is in the forum environment I didn't think it will be considered as a broad question. I suppose in general in the forums users are communicating in a mix formal-informal way (which I guess is closer to the formal).

Comment: *Good one!* can be used to praise a joke— Jane: *Did you hear about the cannibals who ate a missionary and got a taste of religion?* John: *Good one!* — and thus can be used as a dismissive response, as if whatever was said could only be a joke— Jane: *Chris Christie will make a great president.* John: *That's a good one!* As tone is difficult to convey online, be cautious about how you use it on a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but bear in mind that it is colloquial and informal.

There are certainly alternatives, but which you choose depends on the context and the impression you want to give.